# Dynamically detect if logging level is enabled

Tags: python, logging

To reduce stress on my application, I am doing the following:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
DEBUG = log.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)

...

if DEBUG:
    log.debug('blah')
```

Which works fine ... except when I dynamically reconfigure the loggers, which is what I am doing. The `.debug` level is never detected as active, since at app start, when the modules get imported, it was disabled.

Any tip on how to update the module-level `DEBUG` flags after dynamic configuration?

Comment: how about `DEBUG = lambda :  log.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)` and `DEBUG()`?

Comment: That would replace my expensive call to `.debug` by an expensive call to `DEBUG()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the answer is to stop using module-level flags altogether.  I would also skip using `isEnabledFor` since the individual logging methods do this for you since the logging module has always done this AFAICT ([current implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1318)).  I looked as far back as [Python 2.3](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/0df6442ae50619cab1e0b6512b81d65766b38b36#diff-c11fc567cf5b6e518eb855c23b5599bc).

Have you verified that calling `log.debug` is actually a performance problem?